# Remove child products from bundle in order

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

In woocommerce I have hidden child products in bundles from everywhere, so you can't see them at any point in the process of buying the bundle, but after buying it, they appear in the order with the rest of the info, I want to remove them or hide them everywhere, including the order.

I tried to hide them, but while inside the page, the father product, and the childs are 2 separate class, when it comes to the order, they appear as iqual, so I can't just hide the children because they are all the same product class.